# Prove that if $f:G \longrightarrow G'$ is a group homomorphism, $f(x)^{-1} = f(x^{-1})$ for all $x \in G$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify this?

> Prove that if $f:G \longrightarrow G'$ is a group homomorphism, $f(x)^{-1} = f(x^{-1})$ for all $x \in G$

Let $e$ and $e'$ denote the identity elements of $G$ and $G'$, respectively. We first prove an elementary fact: $f(e)=e'$.

\begin{eqnarray}
f(e) &=& f(e \cdot e) \\
f(e)&=& f(e) *f(e) \\
f(e)*f(e)^{-1} &=& f(e)*f(e)*f(e)^{-1} \\
e' &=& f(e)
\end{eqnarray}

Now, let $x \in G$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x \cdot x^{-1}) &=& f(e) \\
&=& e'
\end{eqnarray}

That is,
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) * f(x^{-1}) &=& e' \\
f(x^{-1}) &=& f(x)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Perfect. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Now prove that $f(x^n) = (f(x))^n,\ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$. (Why can't you use this with $n = 0$ and $n = -1$ to prove $f(e) = e'$ and $f(x^{-1}) = (f(x))^{-1}$?)

Comment: As exercises for beginners in group theory, you should perhaps mention **uniqueness** of the inverse element in that last line...good work.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine.

$f(ee)=f(e)\implies f(e)f(e)=f(e)\implies f(e)=e'$

$f(e)=f(gg^{-1})\implies e'=f(g)f(g^{-1})\implies f(g^{-1})=f(g)^{-1}$